# What is the widest road in the world?

Tags: driving, where-on-earth, road-trips

What is the widest road in the world? (road / avenue / street / highway)

Searching online it's quite difficult to find something approaching an accurate answer. What I could find mentioned:

**Monumental Axis**, Brazil

Apparently this has, or had, a Guinness world record at some point. Though I didn't find details, and there are lots of apparently mislabelled photos marked as being this road. It's listed as being 250ft or 250m wide.

**Katy Freeway**, Houston, Texas

Apparently there was some trolling / misinformation from a few months ago. So you can find a few places, and fake images, saying this is the widest.

**G4 Beijing-Hong Kong-Macao Expressway**

The images online I can find of this look less like a road or highway, and more like a waiting area through toll booths. Also many posts saying it has "50 lanes" when there are only at most 25 toll booths.

**I-35 (expansion)**, Houston, Texas

Apparently this may expand to ~22 lanes. Which I only mention because 22 lanes is larger than many photos of above roads.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a trivia question rather than about travel

Comment: I was on-the-fence as to if I should post here or not. Is there a trivia stack exchange? There are a few similar questions here tagged [factoids].

Comment: I-35 does not go through Houston, Texas. It runs from Laredo, Texas, on the Mexico border up to Oklahoma, passing through major cities San Antonio, Austin, and Fort Worth on its way.

Comment: Widest in metres or in lanes?

Comment: Naypyidaw (the new capital of Myanmar) supposedly has a (mostly empty) 20-lane boulevard.

Comment: What counts as "the roadway"? It is common in Texas to have a completely parallel set of continuous "feeder" (aka frontage) lanes to the main lanes. These lanes are at grade level and have stoplight-controlled intersections with major cross streets that themselves pass under the elevated main lanes. The Katy Freeway mentioned in the question follows this design. The main lanes are probably about 12 at widest, with 6 lanes of high-occupancy/toll lanes in the middle and another 8 of frontage/feeder lanes at grade. Are you counting only the 12, or 12+6, or 12+6+8?

Comment: @Midavalo, trivia questions are and have been accepted on Travel Stack Exchange, so that is no reason to close the question.

Comment: Is a car park a road? Some are vast, with marked parking lanes.

Comment: You will end up with quite a few different, but still 'correct' answers all depending on how you define arbitrary details in how to measure a road's width. The Monumental Axis in Brasilia, which you already mentioned, is with six lanes in each directions at a first glance nothing special, but it has a huge park in the middle, making up a 200m wide median, so that the road in total is 250m wide. But do you count the median as part of the road?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo In that case, La Rumorosa (Carretera Federal 2D) between Tecate and Mexicali, Baja California, has a mountain between the Eastbound and Westbound lanes, making it around 4.5km at its widest 

Comment: How about the Bonneville Salt Flats?

Comment: Note that Beijing - Macao/ Hong Kong is several 1000 km. This highway may have lots of lanes and even more toll booths at some points but without a presice location this is useless. My guess for the most lanes stretch would be the end point Hong Kong - Shenzen - Guangzhou.

Comment: Anecdote: A friend of mine who is a traffic planner worked, perhaps 10 years ago, for a planning company in Qatar. Qatar at that time experienced rapid development and a corresponding rapid increase in individual car traffic. The planners devised elaborate plans to cope with that, when the customer representative asked "why do you not simply add more lanes to the roads?" I was curious, too. Apparently, for roads with intersections one limiting factor is the *intersection clearing time* which increases so much that additional lanes do not increase throughput any longer.

Comment: It's not I-35. There is a [Texas State Highway 35](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_State_Highway_35) (SH 35) in Houston. I wasn't able to quickly find a source for the number of planned lanes.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Or maybe they're talking about the project to [reroute and reconstruct I-45](https://www.txdot.gov/nhhip.html), which does go through Houston. [Segment 3](https://www.txdot.gov/nhhip/project-segments/segment3.html) of that project will "widen [I-69/US-59] from 8 to 10 or 12 lanes in each direction."

Comment: @Willeke: Trivia is well-established — but this is a particularly ill-defined trivia question, for many reasons pointed out in comments.  Are median strips included in the width?  Are contiguous feeder/exit ramps counted as part of a road?  How do you measure when an entrance/exit lane becomes a separate feeder/exit ramp?  What about separate roads that run parallel and share a continuous tarmac?  Do we admit facilities that form part of a road, like toll station queue areas?  If so, what about parking lots, port loading areas, etc?  Grey areas in all directions…

Comment: @PLL, use that as a close reason, so far the reason was 'trivia' or better get OP to deline the rules better.

Comment: @Willeke: Yes, it would be great if OP could define some clearer criteria!  In lieu of that, I would indeed be close-voting with this reason, except that I’m not a high-rep user on this site :-)

Comment: "250ft or 250m wide" considering the difference between them, I wouldn't trust those numbers and look for a tertiary source.

Answer (score 10):

If counting lanes, then Yaza Htarni Road in Naypyidaw (the new capital of Myanmar) has up to 20 lanes (2 x 10), here with barely any separation (other sections have a larger median):

[image]

https://maps.app.goo.gl/Nv1G83P3AXS5HjxE9

[image]

A much longer part of the road has 2 x 8 lanes. In total over 11 km have at least 2 x 8 lanes.

Traffic is extremely low, though, and clearly does not justify such a wide road.

Comment: Seems to be about a 83m wide using the Google Maps ruler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryGtP.jpg

Comment: That was the exact thing that sprang to my mind first as well – old Top Gear episodes do have some use, it seems!

Answer (score 4):

[**Avenida 9 de Julio**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenida_9_de_Julio) in Buenos Aires is [recognized](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/108080-widest-avenue) by Guinness as the widest avenue in the world.

[image: Arial photo of Avenida 9 de Julio]

Occupying an entire city block, it's roughly 125m / 410ft from sidewalk to sidewalk.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply search for 'G4 Beijing-Hong Kong-Macao Expressway' you find pictures such as [this](https://9gag.com/gag/azMng2q) which shows a 20 lane each way highway claiming to be the G4 without any more specific location.

However, if you just look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G4_Beijing%E2%80%93Hong_Kong_and_Macau_Expressway) article of the G4, there are a bunch of pictures and none of them has more than 3 or 4 lanes per direction. So the G4 certainly does not look like the first picture the entire way although there may be a stretch of it somewhere that does.

Thanks to user jcaron who linked [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30356/does-china-have-motorways-with-50-lanes-or-at-least-with-20/37473#37473) question on skeptics which concerns exactly the same claim. There at least used to be a toll booth on the G4 highway with around 20 lanes per direction. [Here](https://www.google.de/maps/@39.5493903,116.0340371,481m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu) is a google maps view of the spot. It is in suburbs of Beijing and it looks like the gigantic toll booth doesn't exist anymore. There is still the massive area covered in asphalt but otherwise this seems to be just a regular 4-lane per direction highway.

Comment: Peak lane numbers near large urban areas where they roads are full of local traffic being much higher than the more rural intercity parts is fairly common.

Comment: The image of the G4 highway you are linking to is clearly a fake and composed by replicating a group of lanes multiple times.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that wasn't "just" a widening near a toll plaza, though I am surprised by the lack of any visible signs.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I wondered myself but I don't see any evidence of that, I don't see repetition of the vehicles.

Comment: Probably not the same exact place, but apparently they have similarly wide toll plazas which can end up in nightmare 3-hour traffic jams: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJKN1LzVakA

Comment: Interestingly enough "exact matches" of the picture on Google Images yields about as many "Katy Freeway in Texas" as "G4 in China" (plus a sprinkling of other locales). Seems to have appeared around early September 2020, can't find an original source yet.

Comment: Clearly the G4 has some toll plazas with dozens of lanes (see https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/37473/30616 but that one is definitely not the same place as the linked picture). The majority of the highway is 2 x 4 though.

Comment: @jcaron Multiple images taken at different times have been merged, so that the cars don't repeat, but the ground obviously does. In the left section, there is a distinct pattern of darker tarmac, which is repeating. On the right side, there is one lane separator with a distinct offset, which is repeating where you can also see, that there is a darker section of the tarmac directly right of it: https://media.jarnbjo.de/defb54e2-b350-4808-b49f-14cd18acb160.jpg

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Indeed. But handling the perspective (especially that of the vehicles) must have been... interesting. I wonder what the original intended use of the picture was, this seems to me to be quite a lot of work if just for fun... (but I'm not Photoshop expert so maybe this is just a few clicks!).

Comment: @jcaron The photographer has taken each image from a different position so that the perspective is correct. Surely, it is a bit of effort and more work than just a few clicks, but not particularly difficult. If I had enough time to waste, I could have done such a composition with film and created an analogue print in the dark room. not even needing Photoshop.